# twitter-bootstrap-rails gem workflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, layout, twitter-bootstrap

How do I use the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem in my Rails 3.2.1 app? What is the workflow?

After I do:

```
rails g bootstrap:layout [LAYOUT_NAME] [*ﬁxed or ﬂuid] [options]
```

what do I do next? Do I just copy and paste the generated code into my view? Do I do this for every view? If so, how is doing

```
rails g bootstrap:themed [RESOURCE_NAME] [LAYOUT] [options]
```

any different?

Do you guys even use the rails generators?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a RailsCasts tutorial that is a great starting point:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics

Answer (score 46):

I'm the author of twitter-bootstrap-rails gem. I'll give you a quick walktrough to how to install and use twitter-bootstrap-rails.

Ruby stack;
(Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.1 or Rails 3.2 is required. Use RVM to get started)

After bundling gem to Gemfile by;

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

bundle install
```

#### Run install generator

```
rails g bootstrap:install
```

(it will includes Twitter Bootstrap to your app's asset pipeline)

#### Run layout generator

```
rails g bootstrap:layout application fixed
```

(it will generates layout for you, by default application.html.erb and fixed layout will generates)

#### Run themed generator (optional);

```
rails g scaffold post title:string description:text
```

(this step uses Rails generators to create CRUD stuff for you)

```
rake db:migrate
```

(migrating to database)

```
rails g bootstrap:themed posts
```

(Twitter Bootstrap compatible styling for your 'posts' views and form)

Also there is detailed documentation to install, usage and generators, coffeescript etc.
https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.

Comment: Yes, I use it too and it's great, I'm very satisfied.

Comment: I followed these steps exactly in a new rails app that I started just to test this fancy stuff out. Guess what... It worked PERFECTLY! I like it when simple step-by-step instructions actually bring you to a live, working setup.  Thanks Seyhun!

Comment: @Seyhun, would you be kind enough to tell us how to update the Boostrap version the gem uses? What If I wnated to use the 2.0.2-wip for example... Do I have to modify the files in the gem?

Comment: @Mohamad No, gem supports latest stable release of the TWB. (you can use old versions too). But not wip release.

Comment: You need to add this too: gem 'less-rails' gem 'therubyracer'

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
rails new APPLICATION -m anyfile.rb
```

anyfile.rb

```
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails" 
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"


generate("scaffold", "Post title:string content:text")
rake("db:create")
rake("db:migrate")
generate("bootstrap:layout", "application fluid")
generate("bootstrap:install")
generate("bootstrap:themed", "posts")


git :init
git :add => "."
git :commit => "-m First commit!"
```