# Twitter-bootstrap-rails gem doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm used this workflow, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9125499/3057033

But here is my posts page.

[image]

What I am missing?

I solved my issue. Please look at my answer.

Comment: There is no error in console log.

Comment: Which Rails version are you using ?

Comment: My Rails version is 4.2.5

Comment: have you restart server?

Answer (score 1):

Most common reason of your error is that you forget to add bootstrep styles to your layout

So, in app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss (note that file can be different if you have another layout)

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: Hey edikgat thank you! But this gem add two file to this directory.
```bootstrap_and_overrides.css```,
```bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less```. These files do that for me.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
/*
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
*/
```

to your `application.css`

Answer (score 0):

I'm solving this problem with add `less` the end of the command.

`rails generate bootstrap:install less`

I think newer versions of the Gem need this.

I'm not reading well README file. Just watch the railscasts.

It's my fault, so sorry.